# Google Chrome strange window start xy position

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, window

I've been getting an odd Google Chrome window problem where the startup position of the window is now almost off the screen. I can't find any settings files in `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\3.0.195.38` to control the X and Y position of the window and it's becoming annoying now. Any help is appreciated.

- WinXP Pro
- Chrome version 3.0.195.38
- Dell Inspirion 10" netbook
- No external or extra screens ever used with it

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar issue where the chrome window would be way off screen everytime I started it unless I maximized it. Editing window positions in "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State", as taspeotis suggested, didn't work - the wrong positions got back in it everytime. Even after deleting the entire file. (And yes: I did stop the browser everytime before messing with this Local State file...)

This is what I call way off screen:

```
     "bottom": -31901,
     "left": -32000,
     "right": -31773,
     "top": -32000,
```

What solved it for me was maximizing it (so I could see the window) and then dragging all open tabs to a new window.

Maybe this may help someone else too at some point :-)

Comment: This also worked for me.  I maximised, placed all open tabs in the window.  Sized it to what I wanted it to be from then.  I closed the whole window, and made sure chrome.exe wasn't still running.  Then, opened, and it's remembered.

Answer (score 2):

Open "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State" (convert to Windows XP paths as required)

Edit "window_placement"

More info: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15199

Comment: I'm having this issue in Windows 7 Ultimate with the latest chrome as of 2016/11/12. I don't see any AppData folder on my system..